# Regexp to remove last characters in filenames doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I recently downloaded a bunch of videos using `youtube-dl`, but the program appended characters at the end of the filenames : for example, `Video test` became `Video test-jSbQ40_9B.mp3`. The format is always the same : dash, and about 10 alphanumeric characters or underscores. Why does the following command do nothing?

```
rename 's/[A-Za-z0-9]*\.mp3/\.mp3/' *
```

(I also tried running it as root)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
rename 's/-\w+(\.mp3)$/$1/' *
```

OR else:

```
rename 's/-\w+(?=\.mp3)$//' *
```

Your regex is not matching underscore which is present in your filenames after dash. `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

---

Or without `rename` use:

```
find . -name "*.mp3" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(sed "s/-[^.]*\(\.mp3\)$/\1/" <<< $1)"' - {} +
```

Comment: Actually it still doesn't work... But I wonder whether the problem comes from here or not : The files are on a separate NTFS partition that I have to mount each time. Would that be the cause?

Comment: I moved all the files to my /home/, yet the command still doesn't work. And both the files and the folder have reading and writing permissions.

Comment: Example filename : "I've Got You-hV20RzTvwZE.mp3". The renaming command does nothing, no file is changed, and there isn't any output message. And if I use -v, no files are marked for renaming either.

Comment: When I ran `rename` that file got renamed to `I've Got You.mp3`

Comment: It still doesn't work... I'm going to mark this as "answered" and do it manually. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for acceptance. I have included a `find` command to avoid use of `rename` utility.